# Remove virtual call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Data arrives from a given channel in the following form:

```
void DispatchIncomingChannelData(uint8_t const typeId, 
                                 void * payload, 
                                 uint32_t const payloadSize);
```

The payload may be of several types:

```
struct PayloadA { /* Various Data */ };
struct PayloadB { /* Various Data */ };
struct PayloadC { /* Various Data */ };
// Other PODs...
```

then dispatched to the corresponding handlers:

```
void ProcessPayload_A(PayloadA * payload) { /* PayloadA code */ }
void ProcessPayload_B(PayloadB * payload) { /* PayloadB code */ }
void ProcessPayload_C(PayloadC * payload) { /* PayloadC code */ }
```

Without templates, one could simply provide a switch, and cast away! With a template, I started out as follows:

```
struct BasePayloadProcessor abstract
{
public:
    virtual void ProcessPayload(void * const payload, uint32_t const payloadSize) = 0;
};

// . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

template<typename T>
struct TypedPayloadProcessor : BasePayloadProcessor
{
public:
    using PayloadHandler = void (*)(T * message);

    TypedPayloadProcessor(uint8_t const typeId, PayloadHandler payloadHandler) :
        _payloadHandler { payloadHandler },
        _type { typeid(T) },
        _typeId { typeId }
        { }

    virtual void ProcessPayload(void * const payload, uint32_t const payloadSize) override
    {
        ASSERT(_payloadHandler);
        ASSERT(payloadSize == sizeof(T));
        T * t = reinterpret_cast<T *>(payload);
        _payloadHandler(t);
    }

private:
    PayloadHandler _payloadHandler;
    type_info const & _type;         // <-- These two members are 
    uint8_t const _typeId;           // <-- not really necessary
};
```

And for testing, defined an enum, an array of processors, and hard-coded them.

```
enum class PayloadTypes : uint8_t
{
    Invalid = 0x00,
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x02,
    C = 0x03,
    // etc...
    TotalTypes = static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::C) + 0x01
};

// array of base class pointers
std::array<BasePayloadProcessor *, static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::TotalTypes)> payloadProcessors { };

// populate the array
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::Invalid)] = nullptr;
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::A)] = new TypedPayloadProcessor<PayloadA>(static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::A), ProcessPayload_A);
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::B)] = new TypedPayloadProcessor<PayloadB>(static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::B), ProcessPayload_B);
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::C)] = new TypedPayloadProcessor<PayloadC>(static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::B), ProcessPayload_C);
// etc....
```

And implemented the dispatch function as follows:

```
void DispatchIncomingChannelData(uint8_t const typeId, 
                                 void * payload, 
                                 uint32_t const payloadSize)
{
    ASSERT(typeId > static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::Invalid));
    ASSERT(typeId < static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::TotalTypes));
    payloadProcessors[typeId]->ProcessPayload(payload, payloadSize);
}
```

All works fine.  However I am not happy with this solution.  I would prefer to get rid of the base class, and not keep an array of pointers (due to cache lines).  I am certain there is a better way.  And ultimately, I intend to allow the developer to 'register' their type handler. Thanks.

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I still cannot understand why using a template means you cannot `switch` over the `typeId` and dispatch to the respective handler.

Comment: You certainly could.  And I was pointing out you could remove the template entirely ('Without templates, one could simply provide a switch, and cast away').  The solution above avoids a switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'll just be easier to have an array of `function`s, that you construct with a wrapper:

```
using CallbackFn = std::function<void(void*, const uint32_t)>;

template <typename T>
CallbackFn make_processor(void (*func)(T*))
{
    return [=](void* payload, const uint32_t size){);
        ASSERT(payloadSize == sizeof(T));
        func(static_cast<T*>(payload));
    };
}
```

That way, you can pass the processing functions you already have directly in and have everything just work:

```
std::array<CallbackFn, 
    static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::TotalTypes)> payloadProcessors;

payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::A)] = 
    make_processor(ProcessPayload_A);
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::B)] =
    make_processor(ProcessPayload_B);
payloadProcessors[static_cast<uint8_t>(PayloadTypes::C)] = 
    make_processor(ProcessPayload_C);
```

Comment: That is mostly equivalent to OP's code, but using standard library :-)

Comment: Good point.  That is exactly what I was looking for.  That gets rid of the base class and the virtual call.  I will hold out a bit prior to marking is as answered to allow any others to chime in.  Thanks Barry.

Comment: @Jeff: Note that `std::function` internal may use something similar to the virtual call.

Comment: if you replace the `std::array` with a `std::map` you wouldn't need to cast to a `uint8_t` and you might not have to maintain `PayloadTypes::TotalTypes`, but you'd have to pay for the overhead of using a `std::map` instead of a `std::array`

Comment: @YoungJohn Doesn't that seem like a terrible tradeoff to you?

Comment: I would suppose that depends on the project. If you have a large team with many members continuously updating the different `PayloadTypes` the cost of ease of maintenance might be worth it, especially if this is not an area of performance critical code. Finding that someone failed to update `PayloadTypes::TotalTypes` at run time is never fun.

Comment: @Jarod42 makes a good point. And there is overhead of the capture clause and type generated from the lambda, but this is more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `switch`.**
`default:` catches - and ideally, signals - unsupported types.
It is the most simple code that achieves your desired goal. "Everyone" will understand it.

It also shines on almost all other aspects.

---

What could be improved, compared to switch? The things I can think of are:

- Introducing a new payload type requires introducing a new handler function, a new enum for the type, and adding it to the switch statement. You might forget adding to the switch statement
- If there's more than ca. a dozen values, it's hard to verify visually that all enums and handler match, e.g. you might call the wrong handler.

The last problem remains with all alternatives posted by now, and I can't think of a clever template solution to that.

If there's a larger number of cases, I would consider **code generation**.

Having a file

```
A
B
C
```

could generate the enum of payload types, (forward) declarations for the `struct`s and the handler functions, and the implementation of the central handler with the switch.

Adding another payload type to this file would break the build until you implemented the handler, and then  everything would be in place again.

Downsides are a more complex build process, and the usual issues with generated code.

**[edit]* Don't get me wrong - the question is certainly interesting - and maybe we can come up with a beautiful solution, and/sor learn something from it. It's just the recommendation I'd give for production.

Comment: I appreciate your answer (+1).  I started with a switch, but wanted to make the solution more dynamic and generic (allowing a user to register their type with a corresponding handler).  And I didn't like falling through and testing each case.